# How to update SASS to alpha for use with COMPASS?

Tags: sass, updates, compass-sass

I'm currently using **COMPASS** (version 0.12.2) which AFAIK automatically comes with **SASS** (version 2.9.2 Media Park) under Ubuntu. In order to finally being able to use real source maps (since the newer Google Chrome versions stopped supporting the still current "debug_info" produced by COMPASS/SASS in favour to real source maps) I'd like to update SASS to the version 3.3.0alpha which can produce source maps.

Do I simply `gem install sass -v '>=3.3.0alpha' --pre` and COMPASS will still work fine, or do I have to wait for an updated version of COMPASS that then comes with 3.3 version of SASS?

Any hint welcome.

Cheers, Roman.

Comment: Ok, it seems as if it's not possible. After installing sass 3.3.0alpha, when calling `compass --version` I get `/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in 'require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)`. While then `sass --version` shows that in fact the new version is running: `Sass 3.3.0.alpha.201 (Bleeding Edge)`, trying to call `sass --compass` just results in `ERROR: Cannot load compass.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can simply install Sass from the command line.

Then, run Sass/Compass with `sass --compass --sourcemap styles.scss:styles.css`
`

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work - all I then get is `ERROR: Cannot load compass.` - see my comment to my own question above...

Comment: There's something else in play here then, I can verify it works as can  people in this thread: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1108

Comment: Ok, it seems like you need compass v13 for that, although I yet haven't managed to get that version.

Comment: A little late, but if you get `cannot load compass` you should run `gem uninstall sass, compass` and remove _all_ versions then install it again with `gem install compass --pre` (i still don't get sourcemaps but at least it loads compass! ^_^)

Comment: with the **watch** command: `sass --sourcemap --compass --watch sass:css`